# How to trigger a python method independently from the main program flow?

Tags: python, flask

I am building an interface using python that takes from a collector table -> hands over to a common interface `table -> transform` and fire to an external system. I also have  poller to update status back to both the interface table and collector table.

```
@synch.route("/ssr_synch", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def callSSRSynch():
    batch_txn_id = request.args.get('batch_txn_id')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        batch_txn_id = request.form['batch_txn_id']
        if request.form['synch'] == 'synch':
            if app.config['stub'] == 'False':
                ssr_collector.main()
                ssr_provisioning.main() #for interface table
                ssr_poller.main()
            form = "Synch completed for batch transaction id %s" % (batch_txn_id,)
```

Currently, after the call is trigger by the request, the collector and provisioning run before the poller. I want the poller to be started independent from the collector and provisioning.

Not sure if threading is the best approach or is there an easier solution?

**Update 9-Dec-2015:**

Threading seemed to be the simplest way to do this. managed to make this work:

```
threads = list() 
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=ssr_collector.main, args=(batch_txn_id,))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=ssr_provisioning.main) 
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=ssr_poller.main) 
threads.append(thread1) 
threads.append(thread2) 
threads.append(thread3) 
for t in threads: t.start() 
for t in threads: t.join()
```

Comment: maybe you can use something like celery ?

Comment: threading seemed to be the simplest way to do this. managed to make this work:

`threads = list()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=ssr_collector.main, args=(batch_txn_id,))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=ssr_provisioning.main)
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=ssr_poller.main)
threads.append(thread1)
threads.append(thread2)
threads.append(thread3)
for t in threads: t.start()
for t in threads: t.join()`

Comment: gah! how do i put in `code` in the comments? :p

Comment: edit your answer it's cleaner this way

Answer (score 1):

I think that you went in wrong direction. You should separate different functionality to different applications. Application based on flask framework is your entry point where client can run new task or get information about tasks which currently running or already done. This application should not run task itself or block client connection until task done! There are plenty nice tools which was created special for this use case, [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for example.

Api method:

```
@synch.route("/ssr_synch", methods=['POST'])
def callSSRSynch():
    batch_txn_id = request.args.get('batch_txn_id')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        batch_txn_id = request.form['batch_txn_id']
        if request.form['synch'] == 'synch':
            if app.config['stub'] == 'False':
                collector.delay()
                provisioning.delay()
                poller.delay()         

            form = "Synching for batch transaction id %s" % (batch_txn_id,)
```

Tasks:

```
@celery.task
def collector():
    ssr_collector.main()

@celery.task
def provisioning():
    ssr_provisioning.main()

@celery.task
def poller():
    ssr_poller.main()
```